# Computer Availability (UI form validation)

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, tracking, google-sites

I have created a form that tracks the number of students signing up for a computer lab on a specific day. My problem is I would like to have the form generate a message when an individual begins to sign up and the number of students exceeds the number of available computers, either by the individual or in combination with the number of people already registered for that specific day.

I would also like for it to tell them how many spots are left in the lab if it is not filled.

**My question is that I want to know what code I would add to create a message when too many people have signed up for the lab. I am not sure where to start or how to go about it**

Right now all I do is track numbers of who signed up.

```
//Create the GUI form

function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('DHS: Kurzweil Calendar');

  //Create a panel which holds all the form elelemnts
  var vertMainPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('vertMainPanel');

  //Create the form elelemnts
  var lblTeacherName = app.createLabel('Teacher Name:');
  var txtTeacherName = app.createTextBox().setName('txtTeacherName');

  var lblExt = app.createLabel('Ext:');
  var txtExt = app.createTextBox().setName('txtExt');

  var lblDate = app.createLabel('Date:');
  var boxDate = app.createDateBox().setId('boxDate').setName('boxDate');

  var lbxSubject = app.createListBox().setId('lbxSubject').setName('lbxSubject');
        lbxSubject.setVisibleItemCount(5);
        lbxSubject.addItem('-- Select One --');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Algebra I (OCS)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Algebra II');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Algebra II (Honors)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Agriscience Applications');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Agriscience Applications (OCS)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Anatomy and Physiology');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Anatomy and Physiology (Honors)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Animal Science');
        lbxSubject.addItem('American Sign Language II');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Apparel I');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Art History (AP)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Advanced Functions and Modeling');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Automotive Computer System Diagnostics');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Automotive Brakes');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Automotive Service');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Automotive Service (OCS)'); 
        lbxSubject.addItem('Benchmarks');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Bible History');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Biology');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Biology (AP)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Biology (Honors)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Biology (OCS)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Biomedical Technology');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Biotechnology and Agriscience');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Calculus AB (AP)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Calculus BC (AP)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Carpentry I');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Carpentry I (OCS)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Carpentry III');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Chemistry');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Chemistry (AP)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Chemistry (Honors)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Choral Arts (Beginning)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Civics and Economics');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Civics and Economics (Honors)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Computer Programming I');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Computer Science (AP)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Computer Technology');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Concert Band II (Beginning)');        
        lbxSubject.addItem('Concert Band II (Proficient)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Core and Sustainable Construction');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Core and Sustainable Construction (OCS)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Digital Media I');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Digitial Media I (OCS)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Digital Media II');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Discrete Mathematics');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Drafting I');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Drafting Architecture II (Honors)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Drafting Architecture III (Honors)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Earth and Environmental Science');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Earth and Environmental Sceince (AP)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Earth and Environmental Science (Honors)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Early Childhood Ed I');
        lbxSubject.addItem('eCommerce I (Honors)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('English I');
        lbxSubject.addItem('English I (Honors)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('English II');        
        lbxSubject.addItem('English II (Honors)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('English II (OCS)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('English III');
        lbxSubject.addItem('English III (Honors)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('English III (OCS)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('English IV');
        lbxSubject.addItem('English IV (Honors)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('English IV (OCS)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('English Lang and Comp (AP)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('English Language Arts II');
        lbxSubject.addItem('English Language Arts III');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Engish Literature (AP)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('European History (AP)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Fashion Merchandising');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Financial Management (OCS)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Foods I');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Foods I (OCS)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Foods II - Enterprise');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Foods II - Advanced (OCS)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('French I');
        lbxSubject.addItem('French II');
        lbxSubject.addItem('French III (Honors)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Functional Finances');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Geometry'); 
        lbxSubject.addItem('Geometry (Honors)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('German I');
        lbxSubject.addItem('German II');
        lbxSubject.addItem('German III (Honors)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Health and Physical Education');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Health Sciences (Advanced Studies)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Health Team Relations');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Human Geography (AP)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Holocaust and Peace Studies');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Horticulture I');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Horticulture I (OCS)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Horticulture II');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Horticulture II (OCS)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Integrated Math I');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Interior Design I');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Introduction to Math');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Japanese I');
        lbxSubject.addItem('JROTC I');
        lbxSubject.addItem('JROTC II');
        lbxSubject.addItem('JROTC III');
        lbxSubject.addItem('JROTC IV');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Latin I');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Latim II');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Latin III (Honors)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Leadership Development');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Marketing Management');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Masonry I');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Masonry I (OCS)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Masonry III');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Microsoft Excel and Access');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Microsoft Word PowerPoint and Publisher');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Multimedia and Webpage Design');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Music Business and Recording (Beginning)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Occupational Preparations I');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Occupational Preparations II');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Occupational Preparations III');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Occupational Preparations IV');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Parent and Child Development');        
        lbxSubject.addItem('Parent and Child Development (OCS)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Personal Finance');        
        lbxSubject.addItem('Personal Finance (OCS)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Physical Science');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Physics (Honors)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Pre-Calculus (Honors)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Professional Management and Leadership I');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Professional Management and Leadership II');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Psychology');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Physcology (AP)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Psychology (Honors)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('SAT Preparation');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Science and Technical Visualization I');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Science and Technical Visualization II');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Social Studies (OCS)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Spanish I');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Spanish II');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Spanish III (Honors)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Spanish IV (Honors)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Special Topics of Mathematics');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Symphonic Band II (Beginning)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Symphonic Band II (Intermediate)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Symphonic Band II (Proficient)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Technology Engineering and Design');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Theatre Arts (Beginning)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Theatre Arts (Intermediate)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('US History');
        lbxSubject.addItem('US History (AP)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('US History (Honors)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Visual Arts (Beginning)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Visual Arts (Intermediate)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Visual Arts (Proficient)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Visual Arts (Advanced)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Visual Arts Specialization in Ceramics (Advanced)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Vocal Ensemble (Intermediate)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Vocal Ensemble (Proficient)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Wind Ensemble II (Intermediate)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Wind Ensemble II (Proficient)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('Wind Ensemble II (Advanced)');
        lbxSubject.addItem('World Geography');
        lbxSubject.addItem('World History');
        lbxSubject.addItem('World History');
        lbxSubject.addItem('World History (Honors)');

  var lbxPeriod = app.createListBox().setId('lbxPeriod').setName('lbxPeriod');
        lbxSubject.setVisibleItemCount(1);
        lbxPeriod.addItem('-- Select One --');
        lbxPeriod.addItem('1st Period');
        lbxPeriod.addItem('2nd Period');
        lbxPeriod.addItem('3rd Period');
        lbxPeriod.addItem('4th Period');

  var lblStudentNum = app.createLabel('Number of Students:');
  var txtStudentNum = app.createTextBox().setName('txtStudentNum');

  var radSource1 = app.createRadioButton('group1', 'Hard-Copy').setFormValue('Hard-Copy').setName('Hard-Copy').setId('Hard-Copy');
  var radSource2 = app.createRadioButton('group1', 'Electronic-Copy').setFormValue('Electronic-Copy').setName('Electronic-Copy').setId('Electronic-Copy');

  var radSource3 = app.createRadioButton('group2', 'Teacher-Made Exam').setFormValue('Teacher-Made Exam').setName('Teacher-Made').setId('Teacher-Made');
  var radSource4 = app.createRadioButton('group2', 'Elements Exam').setFormValue('Elements Exam').setName('Elements').setId('Elements');
  var radSource5 = app.createRadioButton('group2', 'Quia Exam').setFormValue('Quia Exam').setName('Quia').setId('Quia');

  var btnCreate = app.createButton('Create Event');

  //Create handler which will execute 'createEvents(e)' on clicking the button
  var evtHandler = app.createServerClickHandler('createEvents');
      evtHandler.addCallbackElement(vertMainPanel);
  //Add this handler to the button
      btnCreate.addClickHandler(evtHandler);

  //Add all the elemnts to the panel 
  vertMainPanel.add(lblTeacherName)
       .add(txtTeacherName)
       .add(lblExt)
       .add(txtExt)
       .add(lblDate)
       .add(boxDate)
       .add(lbxSubject)
       .add(lbxPeriod)
       .add(lblStudentNum)
       .add(txtStudentNum)
       .add(radSource1)
       .add(radSource2)
       .add(radSource3)
       .add(radSource4)
       .add(radSource5)
       .add(btnCreate);

  //Add this panel to the application
  app.add(vertMainPanel);

  //Return the application
  return app;
}

function createEvents(e){

  //Get the active application
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  try{
    //Get the entries
    var ssTeacher = e.parameter.txtTeacherName;
    var ssExt = e.parameter.txtExt;
    var ssSubject = e.parameter.lbxSubject;
    var ssPeriod = e.parameter.lbxPeriod;
    var ssStudentNum = e.parameter.txtStudentNum;
    var ssSource = "";
    var ssType = "";
    var eventDate = e.parameter.boxDate;
    var eventCalSubject = ssPeriod + ": " + ssTeacher + " (" + ssStudentNum + ")";
    var eventCalDetails = "Extension: " + ssExt + "\n" +
          "Subject: " + ssSubject + "\n\n" +
          "Source: " + ssSource + "\n" +
          "Type: " + ssType + "\n";

    //Get the calendar
    var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('davie.k12.nc.us_d2mv2eb8aspuant1vb5j6r3sis@group.calendar.google.com');//Change the calendar id
    //Create the events
    cal.createAllDayEvent(eventCalSubject, Utilities.formatDate(eventDate, 'EST', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), {description:eventCalDetails});

    //Log the entries in a spreadsheet
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0Aur3owCpuUY-dGJIOGZ1LXhqT2FNMGVXSGNJazFnUmc#gid=0');//Change the spreadhseet key to yours
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 10).setValues([[new Date(), eventDate, ssTeacher, ssExt, ssSubject, ssPeriod, ssSource, ssType, ssStudentNum, 'Event created']]);

    //Show the confirmation message
    app.add(app.createLabel('Kurzweil Calendar Event created successfully...'));
    //Make the form panel invisible
    app.getElementById('vertMainPanel').setVisible(false);
    return app;
  }

  //If an error occurs, show it on the panel
  catch(e){
    app.add(app.createLabel('Error occured: '+ e));
    return app;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? And can you share the code you already have that shows the probem you have implementing above requirements?

Comment: I have added my code above and tried to clarify my question...

Comment: What exactly is the problem or difficulty you have with this task?  Have you tried something that is not working correctly?

Comment: I am not sure how to go about getting that type of validation to code correctly and can't find a code resource. I have since actually re-coded the page and updated the source above... I would like to know how to code a validation into the form that would not allow me to schedule for more than 20 computers.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be too hard to get... You just have to store the number of subscriptions in some place (for example in scriptProperties) in your handler function and if it reaches the maximum number then you simply disable the submit button so that no more form can be validated.

In your doGet function it's easy to `setEnable(boolean)` the submit button according to the relevant scriptProperty you have defined and show a label that explains why the subscription is closed.

If you set the limit to 20 then you'll get a maximum of 21 (considering there is 1 computer/reservation) but if you set it to 19 then you get 20.

Comment: Can you give me an example... it sounds like this would work based off the times the form was submitted. However is there a way to make it work based off the TOTAL number of students listed in the spreadsheet on a given day?  The students would be listed by different classes per day, hence needing to have a cut-off.

Comment: without knowing your data it is not easy to give a working example... I guess for you it's clear how you organize your event but not for me...:)

Comment: can the student subscribe for every different subject ? and period ? How do you need to count them ? what are the criteria ?

Comment: The form is for a teacher to fill out to schedule a computer lab. The teacher enters in certain information, specifically date, period, and number of students. Once they hit 'Submit' it creates a calendar event that allows me to see how many students have signed up for the lab per class period and also submits the data to a Google spreadsheet (which is currently not working correctly). **My question is how can I get the total number of students from the database, based on day and period, so I don't allow the teacher to overbook my lab?**

Comment: Yes... I think I may have a better idea how to do it based on what you shared with me over the weekend. We will see how that goes and hopefully have a solution soon.